# Use EBGaramond-LF numbers in math mode and with siunitx

Tags: math-mode, fonts, pdftex, siunitx

I wanna use EBGaramond-LF figures for siunitx such that the following **digits**  are of the same font (EBGaramond-LF):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}   % replace sistyle, siunits, units
\usepackage[]{ebgaramond}
\DeclareSymbolFont{numbers}{T1}{EBGaramond-LF}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{numbers}{"30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}\mathalpha{numbers}{"31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}\mathalpha{numbers}{"32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}\mathalpha{numbers}{"33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}\mathalpha{numbers}{"34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}\mathalpha{numbers}{"35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}\mathalpha{numbers}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}\mathalpha{numbers}{"37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}\mathalpha{numbers}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}\mathalpha{numbers}{"39}   



\begin{document}
$28508$ (standard)

$\num{28508}$ (siunitx)
\end{document}
```

Related to this question [Use libertine numbers in math mode and with siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291755/use-libertine-numbers-in-math-mode-and-with-siunitx) but using pdflatex.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but using

```
\usepackage[detect-all,math-rm=]{siunitx}
```

solves the problem.